# Is de Rham cohomology a generalized cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I guess that the de Rham cohomology $H^{*}_{dR}(M)$ of a smooth manifold $M$ is naturally isomorphic to a cellular cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{R}$. To do this, we need only check that de Rham cohomologies setisfy the axioms of generalized cohomology theory since I already know the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Given an ordinary cohomology theory $H^*(\_,\_;\pi)$ with coefficient $\pi$, then there exists a natural isomorphism $H^*(X,A;\pi)\cong H^*(C^*(X,A;\pi))$ under which the natural transformation $\delta$ agrees with the natural transformation induced by the connecting homomorphism associated to the short exact sequence
> $$0\rightarrow C^*(X,A;\pi)\rightarrow C^*(X;\pi)\rightarrow C^*(A;\pi)\rightarrow 0.$$

Here $C^*(X,A)$ is a cellular cochain complex of a CW pair $(X,A)$. Furthermore, I will write the axioms of ordinary cohomology theory:

> **Definition.** Let $q$ denote all integers. An ordinary cohomology theory $H^{*}$ with coefficient Abelian group $\pi$ is defined to be a system of functors $H^q(X, A;\pi)$ from the homotopy category of pairs of spaces to the category of Abelian groups and natural transformations $\delta :H^q(A;\pi)\rightarrow H^{q+1}(X,A;\pi)$, where $H^q(X;\pi):=H^q(X, \varnothing;\pi)$, that satisfy the following axioms:
>
> > **DIMENSION.** If $X$ is a point, then for all $q\neq0$,
> > $$H^0(X;\pi)=\pi ;$$
> > $$H^q(X;\pi)=0.$$
> > **EXACTNESS.** The following sequence is exact, where $i:A\rightarrow X$ and $j:(X, \varnothing)\rightarrow (X, A)$ are the inclusions:
> > $$...\rightarrow H^q(X,A;\pi) \xrightarrow{j^*} H^q(X;\pi) \xrightarrow{i^*} H^q(A;\pi) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^{q+1}(X,A;\pi) \rightarrow ...$$
> > **EXCISION.** If $(X; A, B)$ is an excisive triad, then the inclusion $(A, A\cap B)\rightarrow (X, B)$ induces an isomorphism
> > $$H^*(X,B;\pi)\rightarrow H^*(A, A\cap B;\pi)$$
> > **ADDITIVITY.** If $(X, A)$ is the disjoint union of a set of pairs $(X_i, A_i)$, then the inclusions $(X_i, A_i)\rightarrow (X, A)$ induce an isomorphism
> > $$H^*(X,A;\pi)\rightarrow \prod_i H^*(X_i, A_i;\pi)$$
> > **WEAK EQUIVALENCE.** If $f:(X, A)\rightarrow (Y, B)$ is a weak equivalence, then
> > $$f^*:H^*(Y,B:\pi)\rightarrow H^*(X,A;\pi)$$
> > is an isomorphism.

Let $\Omega^*(M)$ denote the de Rham complex of a smooth manifold $M$. I define the de Rham  complex of $M$ together with a smooth embedded submanifold $L$ of $M$ to be

$$\Omega^*(M,L):=ker(\Omega^*(M)\rightarrow \Omega^*(L)),$$

where $\Omega^*(M)\rightarrow \Omega^*(L)$ is a cochain map specified by the pushout map of the smooth embedded inclusion $L\rightarrow M$. In this notation, we define an $n$-th de Rham cohomology of $(M,L)$ to be

$$H^{n}_{dR}(M,L):=H^n(\Omega^*(M,L)).$$

Does the de Rham cohomology theory $H^*_{dR}(\_,\_)$ satisfy all of the axioms? I have already seen the dimension axiom

$$H^0_{dR}(M)=\mathbb{R};$$
$$H^q_{dR}(M)=0$$

if $M$ is a point and $q\neq0$. So I would like to verify the others. But I cannot do it. For example, to do the exactness, I wish that the following sequence of cochain complexes is exact:

$$0\rightarrow\Omega^*(M,L)\rightarrow\Omega^*(M)\rightarrow\Omega^*(L)\rightarrow0$$

because the desired sequence will be obtained by applying cohomology to the above exact sequence. But I cannot find the exactness of $\Omega^*(M)\rightarrow\Omega^*(L)\rightarrow0$. In the other parts of it, I cannot also do a thing. Is my attempt incorrect? Could you give me advice, or some references? I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: de Rham cohomology is not defined for every pair of spaces.

Comment: Nor is it defined for non-manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Of course, I know it. Once again, my question is how to find a natural isomorphism from the de Rham cohomology of **a smooth manifold $M$** to the cellular cohomology of $M$. To do it, I would like to see that de Rham cohomology satisfies these properties in the axioms on **a pair $(M,L)$ of smooth manifolds**. Then it will be proved as same as the head theorem, using these properties, right? That is, I guess that de Rham cohomology is an ordinary cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{R}$ on the homotopy category of  pairs of **smooth manifolds**.

Comment: The usual way is to show that de Rham cohomology agrees with sheaf cohomology, and then show sheaf cohomology agrees with singular cohomology, I think.

Comment: Careful with the definition of $\Omega(M,L)$. Forms on $M$ that vanish on $L$ are different from those whose restrictions to $L$ vanish.